# How to disable enter key in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop the enter key from triggering all actions from other scripts on input fields.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {

      var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 

          if (code  == 13) {  
          // alert('enter pressed');
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;

      }
 });
```

An example of the code in action is here http://jsfiddle.net/8SJYn/ , 
It should be disabling enter but it is not.

Opinions?

Comment: In a general sense if you bind a keydown handler to the individual elements _before_ other handlers are bound then you can use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent the other handlers from running, but you can't use that technique with a handler bound to the `document` because that handler is executed last after the event bubbles up through the DOM. In your case though you can't bind directly to the individual inputs with `$("input").bind(...` because the `.tagit()` plugin hides the input and replaces it with another structure.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, you don't need to test `e.keyCode`: just use `e.which` directly, because jQuery normalises it for you.

Comment: yes it creates another input element, which means your solution to bind to all inputs should work, but it does not. It triggers (i put an alert in there) but it doesn't stop execution

Comment: No, binding all inputs doesn't work in this case because jQuery executes handlers in the order they're bound, and any inputs created by `.tagit()` don't exist if you try to bind handlers before calling `.tagit()`, but if you bind _after_ then the other handlers are already bound too.

Comment: then why does it not work if i bind this to a shell div which encases all of these elements

Comment: Binding to a container doesn't work for reasons already given.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by turning off the keydown and blur events for the input created by the tagit for this element alone.

Try this:

```
$('#myTags + ul .ui-autocomplete-input').off('keydown').off('blur');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JzJRY/

Comment: this works but it disables all keydown triggers.. i wish to select which keys are disabled

Comment: @SeanFlannery WHat you mean by all keydown triggers? can you elaborate?

Comment: there are other keydown triggers on this field, eg. on keydown comma, on keydown enter, on keydown tab, on keydown backspace.. i don't want to disable all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Go into tag-it.js, and on line 245, find this part and remove it:

```
event.which === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER
```

Comment: I don't want to edit other scripts, i want to override execution.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript events have a "bubbling" phase, where they fire first on the inner-most DOM element, and then work their way up to the top-level document. If you try to stop the event at the document level, as in your example code, it is too late.

In some browsers (Firefox, for one) there is a "capturing" phase that occurs before the bubbling phase, and it works in the opposite direction: from top down. You cannot add a capturing phase event handler using jQuery. You must use the native `addEventListener` function and pass `true` as the third parameter. If you add the code below into your jsfiddle, it will prevent the Enter keydown event *in some browsers*.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        // alert('Enter keydown');
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

Be aware that the tag-it control in your jsfiddle also performs its text-to-tag conversions on blur, so if you uncomment the alert statement above, it will perform its text-to-tag conversion anyway, because of the blur event that occurs when the alert message is displayed.

Lastly, if you want to prevent not just other scripts from processing the Enter keydown, but also the browser itself, add an `e.preventDefault();` line to the above.

Comment: i attempted to use this by binding it to $('input') but was unsuccessful. is this dcument specific?

Comment: $('input').each(function (i, element) { element.addEventListener(...); });

Comment: ^ Because addEventListener is a native function, not a jQuery function, you need to loop through the native elements like that.